# How to set delegate on CustomToolbar in rootViewController using a NavigationController setup with initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, uitoolbar

How to set a delegate for a CustomToolbar in the rootViewController when using a NavigationController setup with initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:

In my code I am doing the following:

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithClassName:kFTPostClassKey];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CustomNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:[CustomToolbar class]];
[navController setViewControllers:@[rootViewController] animated:NO];

// Present the Home View Controller
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

In the 'RootViewController' I am trying to set the delegate for the toolbar in order to detect when an item is tapped.

```
[self.navigationController.toolbar setDelegate:self];
```

When I do this I get an exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot manually set the delegate on a UIToolbar managed by a controller.'
```

I looked at the documentation and learned that you can not set the delegate when the toolbar is being managed by the UINavigationController. My question is this: How can I detect clicks on the CustomToolbar in my RootViewController if I can not set the delegate?

I would also appreciate some deeper explanation, as I am new and not sure how this is all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that in order to work, the `navigationController` needs to be the `navigationBar` `delegate`. That's why you can not set the `navigationBar` `delegate` when it is used in a `navigationController`.

As you use a subclass of `navigationBar`, you can try to have a subprotocol of the `UINavigationBarDelegate` in which you add a navigationBarWasSelected method. 
In a new `UINavigationController` subclass, you implement this method to let the `rootViewController` now when the navigation is clicked.

Or, in your custom navigation bar you can send a `NSNotification` in the `NSNotificationCenter`, and catch it in your `RootViewController`.